# open a new pop-up window from a link when you click

Tags: php

```
echo "<a href="http://www.quackit.com/common/link_builder.cfm" onclick="basicPopup(this.href);return false">Open a popup window</a>";
```

I am new to PHP. I am currently having the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'http' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in search.php on line 91

I know its a syntax error, but I have tried many times, and still can't solve the problem.

Comment: You didn't escape your quotes.  This is a daily question on StackOverflow.

Comment: thanks for helping... Problems solve

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the quotes, however you don't need to echo it at all. If you need to echo variables inside the url, try this:

```
<a href="http://www.quackit.com/common/link_builder.cfm?<?php echo $variable;?>" onclick="basicPopup(this.href);return false">Open a popup window</a>
```

alternatively, you can escape the quotes inside the string using a backslash:

```
echo "<a href=\"http://www.quackit.com/common/link_builder.cfm\" onclick=\"basicPopup(this.href);return false\">Open a popup window</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the quote or use single quote solved the problem.

Try

Escape the double quote within the quote

```
<?php
echo "<a href=\"http://www.quackit.com/common/link_builder.cfm\" onclick=\"basicPopup(this.href);return false\">Open a popup window</a>";

?>
```

or

Use single quote

```
<?php
    echo "<a href='http://www.quackit.com/common/link_builder.cfm\' onclick='basicPopup(this.href);return false'>Open a popup window</a>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<?php

echo "<a href='http://www.quackit.com/common/link_builder.cfm' onclick='basicPopup(this.href);return false'>Open a popup window</a>";

?>
```